# How do I extend NSButtonCell with a method in NSButton?

Tags: objective-c, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

I am unfamiliar with the subclassing or extending Cocoa framework.
NSButton has a `setToolTip` method, however NSButtonCell does not.  I rather not add new IBOutlets, so how can I accomplish this by accessing NSButton's method?

I have a series of checkboxes, all with NSButtonCell outlets.  I am unable to access the setToolTip method but if i were to make an NSButton outlet on the same thing, i do, seems to be where i am stuck.

```objectivec
/* Tooltips require you to connect the NSButton not NSButtonCell */
   [myButton setToolTip:@"This does xyz"];
```

Comment: You might want to edit your topic to clarify which one you are asking about, but note that they both have a view, which is what gets the tooltip.

Comment: Ohh! `[myButton.controlView setToolTip:@"tool tip"];` seems to have done the trick @red_menace - is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, your edit clarified the situation.  While `NSButton` inherits from `NSView`, you need to take a sidestep with `NSButtonCell` by getting its `controlView` property in order to get the view for the tooltip.

Comment: I would like to accept your comment as the answer, mind answering so you can get the credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip in this case comes from `NSView`.  `NSButton` inherits from `NSView`, but you need to take a little sidestep with `NSButtonCell` by using its `controlView` property to get the view for the cell, for example:

```
[myButtonCell.controlView setToolTip:@"tool tip"];
```